# how to Add the days using Dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hello every one hope you are fine :)
i need help i want to change the date from selecting the days,weeks and months from dropdown list and input the number of days,weeks and months from textbox, here are all code is working fine if i input the days in digits but not working or changing the date from selecting dropdown list
here is the javascript

```
<script>
        function addDate() {
            debugger;
            //Get the entered datevalue
            var enteredDateVal = new moment(document.getElementById("TextBoxStartDate").value);
            //Get the days to add 
            var numberofDays = document.getElementById("TextBoxpredictDays").value
            //Add the days using add method in moment.js
            enteredDateVal.add("Days", parseInt(numberofDays));
            //Assign the value in textbox
            document.getElementById("TextBoxPredictedClosing").value = enteredDateVal.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
        }
    </script>
```

here is my button click code behind but i want in dropdown how to do this i do not know :(

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dtval = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxStartDate.Text);
            //Add values here
            DateTime formatteddays = dtval.AddDays(Int16.Parse(TextBoxpredictDays.Text));
            TextBoxPredictedClosing.Text = formatteddays.ToString("DD-MM-YYYY");
        }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `alert` `document.getElementById("TextBoxStartDate");` and what does it gives you?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I thought about was a Combobox. That´s the way I would do it, if I got your point.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static ComboBox DropDown;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] listMonth = { "01", "02", "03", "04" };

        DropDown = new ComboBox();
        DropDown.Parent = this;
        DropDown.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50);
        DropDown.Items.AddRange(listMonth);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dropDownText = DropDown.Text;
    }
}
```